# c3 graph in a dark background; how to change axis and tick value color

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3

I have plotted a graph on a dark background but due to the axis-color and tick-value color it is very difficult to read. How do I change to color of the axis, ticks and axis tick value to white?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `CSS` to style the graph, for example

```
path.domain { stroke: white; }
.tick text { stroke: yellow; }
.c3-legend-item text { stroke: grey; }
```

To make the axis white, the tick labels yellow, and the legend text grey.

Comment: For example use the CSS selector `.c3-legend-item text`

Comment: That creates a stroke though and it does not change the color. Is there a way to just change the text color instead of creating a stroke?

Answer (score 3):

```
.c3 path, .c3 line, .tick text { 
  stroke: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also changing the color of the fill if you don't want to use a stroke:

```
path.domain { fill: white; }
.tick text { fill: yellow; }
.c3-legend-item text { fill: grey; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to adjust the CSS properties of the path and line. See the example CSS below as a helper.

```
.c3 .c3-axis-x path,
.c3 .c3-axis-x line {
  stroke: red;
}

.c3 .c3-axis-y path,
.c3 .c3-axis-y line {
  stroke: blue;
}
```